# Which one is better to name a third party spring boot starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, naming-conventions, naming

According to spring boot official, name a third party spring boot starter should not start with "spring-boot". It is recommend use pattern: third-spring-boot-starter.

But if the third part has more than one starters, how to name them?

```
third-module1-spring-boot-starter
third-module2-spring-boot-starter
```

or

```
third-spring-boot-starter-module1
third-spring-boot-starter-module1
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Relying on the naming convention from the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-developing-auto-configuration), the following naming is closer to their suggestion:

```
third-spring-boot-starter-module1
third-spring-boot-starter-module2
```

I think it is a common case to have multiple starters for a bigger organization like:

```
third-spring-boot-starter-logging
third-spring-boot-starter-tracing
```

and giving the actual name of the module at the end, is more similar to what the Spring Boot team is doing.